# App Link synthetic back stack not working in compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking, applinks, android-13

As per https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles all the screens mentioned as start destinations should get added to backstack.

I can verify that it works fine by using `adb -d shell 'am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "<url>"' <package-name>`.

However, when we open the same destination using an app link https://developer.android.com/training/app-links, only the exact destination opened, on backpress, the app exits. This happens only in Android 13 phones and works fine in Android 12 and below. It this the default behaviour in Android 13 or is there a way to override the same?